# Primefaces ajaxstatus error(dialog is not defined)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I used the same one as in primefaces.org which is: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatusScript.jsf

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"       onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"   
    draggable="false" closable="false">  
<p:graphicImage value="/design/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />  
</p:dialog>
```

my page never shows the content if this piece of code exists. When I inspect with firebug, the js error is Uncaught ReferenceError: statusDialog is not defined.

Comment: Not sure of what exactly happening but instead you can have your ajaxStatus like this 
<p:ajaxStatus>
<f:facet name="start">
<p:graphicImage value="ajaxloading.gif" />
</f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>

Comment: but with this I can not show effect as dialog.

Comment: check the diference <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();"/>

Comment: maybe you can use BlockUI component, http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/home.jsf

Answer (score 8):

What Primefaces´ version are you using?

Primefaces from 4 to 5 changed the way to access widget components:

> Widgets must be referenced via "PF". e.g. PF('widgetVarName').show()
>   instead of widgetVarName.show();

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide

Comment: save my day, Thanks a lot